# Trying to add more space to write in lesson plans

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Hello - I am trying to use this existing google sheet document to write my lesson plans into. They are formatted like this because the principal of my school used this to make a "hard copy" of the entire school year. I prefer to use things online so I can link my documents through google drive. I cannot seem to find a easy way (lots of extra sheets to do fixes on) in order to type line for line into the spot highlighted.

Anyways I really do not know how I can help this without Major reformatting which would be very time consuming. Any help you can offer would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do (i.e., "in order to type line for line into the spot"). Could you show an example of what you want to do? Right now, all we see is a blank cell.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Format > Wrapping > Wrap** to make multiline text easier to view, and press **Control+Enter** to insert line breaks where necessary.

To insert links, choose **Insert > Link** while editing a cell.